# Setting rows of different colours in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable

Good afternoon,
I've got a problem with my render class used to render a JTable. What I want is to set the background colour of the rows 1 to 4 to blue, from 5 to 6 to orange, and from 18 to 20 to red. However, it doesn't let me do it. I do not receive any kinds of errors, but this code just lets me set only one of those three conditions. If i put this code, the only thing that pops up in the table are the last three rows in red, and I want the three rows at the same time.

```
class TeamBold extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private String nombre;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        JLabel parent = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value.equals(nombre)) {
            parent.setFont(parent.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD)); //Here I just set a certain cell to bold
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<table.getRowCount();i++) {

        }
        if (row >= 0 && row <4) {
            parent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (row >= 4 && row <6) {
            parent.setBackground(Color.orange);
            parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        } 
        if (row >= 17 && row <19) {
            parent.setBackground(Color.RED);
            parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        } 
        else {
            parent.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the `JTable`. This approach will work even if you table has String, Integer, objects in your model. Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information.

A basic implementation of this suggestion  would be something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(25, 5)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if (isRowSelected(row)) return c;

        //  Customize row colors

        c.setBackground( getBackground() );
        c.setForeground( getForeground() );

        if (row < 4)
        {
            c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else if (row < 6)
        {
            c.setBackground(Color.orange);
            c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else if (row >= 17 && row < 20)
        {
            c.setBackground(Color.RED);
            c.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        return c;
    }
};
```

You would need to use the `getVauleAt(...)` method to get the value to determine if you want to make the cell bold.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` only covers the last `if`.

Also, not sure if you wanted to set foreground or background in the `else` block.

I assume you want `else`s like:

```
    if (row >= 0 && row <4) {
        parent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (row >= 4 && row <6) {
        parent.setBackground(Color.orange);
        parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (row >= 17 && row <19) {
        parent.setBackground(Color.RED);
        parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        // setForeground?? - currently whatever was set last time through.
        parent.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
```

Also the font is usually left to whatever was set last time.

Probably better written something like:

import static java.awt.Color.*;

```
    Component component = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column
    );

    // Here we just set a certain cell to bold
    component.setFont(parent.getFont().deriveFont(
        value.equals(nombre) ? Font.BOLD: Font.PLAIN
    )); 

    final Color fg;
    final Color bg;
    if (0 <= row && row < 4) {
        fg = WHITE; bg = BLUE;
    } else if (row <= 4 && row < 6) {
        fg = WHITE; bg = ORANGE;
    } else if (17 <= row && row < 19) {
        fg = WHITE; bg = RED;
    } else {
        fg = BLACK; bg = WHITE;
    }
    component.setForeground(fg);
    component.setBackground(bg);
```

(Note, `this` works as well a `component`, but you do need to set it up.)

Answer (score 0):

There were the "else" blocks remaining. This is the code.

```js
JLabel parent = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
  if (value.equals(nombre)) {
   parent.setFont(parent.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
  }

  if (row >= 0 && row < 4) {
   parent.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
  } else if (row >= 4 && row < 6) {
   parent.setBackground(Color.orange);
   parent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  } else if (row >= 17 && row < 20) {
   parent.setBackground(Color.RED);
   parent.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
  } else {
   parent.setForeground(Color.black);
   parent.setBackground(Color.white);
  }
  return parent;
```